# SKSpriteNode not initializing

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg_blank")
    background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    background.position = CGPoint.zero
    self.addChild(background)
}
```

The preceding code is supposed to add a background node to the scene covering the entirety of the screen. I don't receive any errors, yet the node count is 0. Why isn't the node displaying, and how would I fix the code to do so?